# How to convert PSD icons to things I can use with <span>

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, svg, icons, glyphicons

To be clear I'm definitely not a very good graphics person... but I needed some number icons, and looking all over IcoMoon I could only find one set: http://brankic1979.com/icons/. The problem is I was expecting a CSS sheet or something I could download and then reference like a Bootstrap glyphicon, e.g., `<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-name"></span>`. This set is downloaded as a PSD file. Honestly I have no idea whatsoever where to go from here...

It seems like I can use IcoMoon to generate the icon if I import an SVG file, but I have no idea how to convert the PSD file items to an SVG file (I tried to copy one individually to a new canvas, but save as SVG is not an option). Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following in Photoshop:
file > export > export as... >

than in the top right corner you see an area called file settings and then it says format. You just click the drop down and change it to a SVG.

Comment: to be clear, what I'm saying is I don't know how to use it